# Visual Studio adds a duplicate reference when creating NUnit Test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a simple .sln with 2 projects:

-- .NET standard Library

-- NUnit Test Project

The issue presents itself when I add the NUnit Test Project to the .sln because VisualStudio adds another reference to the test inside the .NET standard Library project (see picture).

Screenshot from VS Explorer:

[image: Screenshot from VS Explorer]

This folder is not physically present on my laptop but still is causing several build errors for duplicate references.

To add more information:

Deleting the NUnit Test from the Library project will make the Test unavailable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEd1A.png)

Comment: What's inside ?

Comment: Why the folder is there I don't know, but you can try and remove it from the project via solution explorer, clean and build, see if that works.

Comment: Removing the test from the Library will make the NUnit test unavailable. I've edited the post to add the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the culprit even though I'm not sure why it behaves like that.
My solution structure was

```
-- sln 

  -- Folder

    -- .Net Library

    --  NUnit Test
```

Eliminating the folder will eliminate this strange behavior and adding the NUnit test will not create a duplicate inside the .Net Library.